# LeanFT & Selenium custom automation framework - no HTML report generated

Tags: java, selenium, leanft

I have been trying to make LeanFT html reports work with my Selenium/Junit framework, however so far without any joy. 
I have searched the topic multiple times on different forums incl. HP official materials and tried all setup methods that I could find.
An XML runresults file is still generated when using a custom Selenium/LeanFT framework.

I create a LeanFT Testing Project project using JUnit as my framework and Selenium as SDK. I also add relevant Selenium jars.

LeanFT version is 14.0.2816.0.
I am conscious of this issue: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UFT-Practitioners-Forum/HTML-report-not-generated-in-custom-framework-using-LeanFT/td-p/1614027 .

**I would be grateful, if someone could explain where I am making a mistake here or if the software version is the problem here.** Any help is very much appreciated.

The actual setup contains more abstractions, is generally more complex and runs as a jar file, but I have simplified the code for the purpose of this topic as the outcome of both setups is the same - a runresults.xml and no html:

- Test Class:

  ```
  import com.hp.lft.report.CaptureLevel;
  import com.hp.lft.report.ModifiableReportConfiguration;
  import com.hp.lft.report.Reporter;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.ModifiableSDKConfiguration;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.SDK;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.Browser;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserDescription;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory;
  import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserType;
  import core.Selenium;
  import org.junit.After;
  import org.junit.AfterClass;
  import org.junit.Before;
  import org.junit.BeforeClass;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
  import org.openqa.selenium.*;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.net.URI;


  public class SeleniumTest extends Selenium {

      WebDriver driver;
      Browser browser;

      public SeleniumTest() {
          //Change this constructor to private if you supply your own public constructor
      }


      @BeforeClass
      public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

          instance = new SeleniumTest();
          globalSetup(SeleniumTest.class);


      }

      @AfterClass
      public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
          globalTearDown();

      }

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
          ModifiableSDKConfiguration sdkConfig = new ModifiableSDKConfiguration();
          sdkConfig.setServerAddress(new URI("ws://localhost:5095"));
          SDK.init(sdkConfig);
          ModifiableReportConfiguration reportConfig = new ModifiableReportConfiguration();
          reportConfig.setOverrideExisting(true);
          reportConfig.setTargetDirectory("C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\LeanFT_Selenium\\RunResults");
          reportConfig.setReportFolder("LastRun");
          reportConfig.setTitle("Summary");
          reportConfig.setDescription("Description");
          reportConfig.setSnapshotsLevel(CaptureLevel.All);

          Reporter.init(reportConfig);

          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addExtensions(new File
                  ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HP\\Unified Functional Testing\\Installations\\Chrome\\Agent.crx"));
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                  "C:\\HP_Reporting\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
          DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
          capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
          driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
          browser = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder()
                  .type(BrowserType.CHROME).build());
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {

          driver.quit();
          browser = null;

          Reporter.generateReport();
          SDK.cleanup();
      }

      @Test
      public void test() throws Exception {

          driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");

      }
  }
  ```
- Selenium Class:

  ```
  import com.hp.lft.report.Status;
  import com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase;
  import org.junit.After;
  import org.junit.Before;
  import org.junit.ClassRule;
  import org.junit.Rule;
  import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;

  public class Selenium  extends UnitTestBase{

      protected static Selenium instance;

      public static void globalSetup(Class<? extends Selenium> testClass) throws Exception {
          if (instance == null)
              instance = testClass.newInstance();
          instance.classSetup();
      }

      @Before
      public void beforeTest() throws Exception {
          testSetup();
      }

      @After
      public void afterTest() throws Exception {
          testTearDown();
      }

      public static void globalTearDown() throws Exception {
          instance.classTearDown();
          getReporter().generateReport();
      }

      @ClassRule
      public static TestWatcher classWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
          @Override
          protected void starting(org.junit.runner.Description description) {
              className = description.getClassName();
          }
      };

      @Rule
      public TestWatcher watcher = new TestWatcher() {
          @Override
          protected void starting(org.junit.runner.Description description) {
              testName = description.getMethodName();
          }
          @Override
          protected void failed(Throwable e, org.junit.runner.Description description) {
              setStatus(Status.Failed);
          }

          @Override
          protected void succeeded(org.junit.runner.Description description) {
              setStatus(Status.Passed);
          }
      };

      @Override
      protected String getTestName() {
          return testName;
      }

      @Override
      protected String getClassName() {
          return className;
      }

      protected static String className;
      protected String testName;



  }
  ```

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffAdA.png)

Comment: **(1)** `UnitTestBase` does the `SDK` and `Reporter` initialization already, so by doing it too in the Test Class, you're doing it twice. If you don't want to do it in the `Selenium` class just remove the `extends UnitTestBase` bit. **(2)** You say you are aware that in 14.00 the report is not generated with custom framework (meaning you init and generate it yourself) yet here you are, doing that exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, I was aware of that, however I thought that perhaps there was a way to work around it or people had different experience. What do you mean by initialising and generating the html myself? And also I believe that the modifiable sdk and init have to be introduced if one is not using the native LeanFT sdk, so I thought that sdk and reporter in Selenium were there to introduce new modifiable sdk and modifiable reporter, not duplicating UnitTestBase.

Comment: If no one answers ‘till tomorrow, I will return with a comprehensive answer myself.

Comment: FWIW, we've abandoned as much of the leanft framework as we can so that we have more flexibility. While this is useful for a new testing project like mine, it may not be feasible for projects that have existed for some time. In our case, we use the TestNG test report (instead of JUnit) and we have acceptable results. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **TL;DR**

The report is only generated in 14.00 by extending `UnitTestBase`. To have the report generated with a custom automation framework, you must upgrade to at least LeanFT 14.01 (latest one at the time of writting is 14.02 though).

<sub>*Oh, and just for clarification: this issue has nothing to do with Selenium. You'd have the same behavior in C# LeanFT SDK using NUnit 3, for example.*</sub>

## **Details**

**What is a custom automation framework in this context?**

When I say custom automation framework I mean any framework that does the `SDK` and `Reporter` initialization and cleanup itself.

LeanFT does all the magic through its engine. To tell a custom framework to connect to the engine, you need perform the following steps:

- at the beginning of a test suite:

  ```
  SDK.init();
  Reporter.init(); // This is not for the engine, but for the HTML report generation
  ```
- at the end of a test suite

  ```
  Reporter.generateReport();
  SDK.cleanup();
  ```

When you are using the builtin templates, you'll notice that a `UnitTestClassBase` class is automatically created, that extends from `UnitTestBase` and that your `LeanFtTest` class extends from this `UnitTestClassBase`.

By doing so you are initializing the `SDK` and the `Reporter` in a very specific way, which is the reason why with this initialization the HTML report is generated. If you were to reproduce this specific way in your *custom* framework, you'll also have the HTML report generated. If you are curious, you can check the contents of the `UnitTestBase.class` file to see what it does.

**You are extending from UnitTestBase. Why is it not working?**

As mentioned in my comments, you are actually doing the `SDK` and `Reporter` initialization twice, once by extending the `UnitTestBase` (which, as I described above, does that initialization already) and the second time in your `setUp` method.

Since you are using LeanFT 14.00, you should let the `UnitTestBase` do the initialization, cleanup and report generation. This means that your Test Class file should be changed to no longer include the init of the `SDK` and `Reporter`, as follows:

```
import com.hp.lft.report.CaptureLevel;
import com.hp.lft.report.ModifiableReportConfiguration;
import com.hp.lft.report.Reporter;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.ModifiableSDKConfiguration;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.SDK;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.Browser;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserDescription;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserType;
import core.Selenium;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;


public class SeleniumTest extends Selenium {

    WebDriver driver;
    Browser browser;

    public SeleniumTest() {
        //Change this constructor to private if you supply your own public constructor
    }


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

        instance = new SeleniumTest();
        globalSetup(SeleniumTest.class);


    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        globalTearDown();

    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {


    /*
        This will not work in LeanFT 14.00, so we are commenting it out

        ModifiableSDKConfiguration sdkConfig = new ModifiableSDKConfiguration();

        sdkConfig.setServerAddress(new URI("ws://localhost:5095"));
        SDK.init(sdkConfig);
        ModifiableReportConfiguration reportConfig = new ModifiableReportConfiguration();
        reportConfig.setOverrideExisting(true);
        reportConfig.setTargetDirectory("C:\\Users\\user\\IdeaProjects\\LeanFT_Selenium\\RunResults");
        reportConfig.setReportFolder("LastRun");
        reportConfig.setTitle("Summary");
        reportConfig.setDescription("Description");
        reportConfig.setSnapshotsLevel(CaptureLevel.All);

        Reporter.init(reportConfig);
    */
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File
            ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\HP\\Unified Functional Testing\\Installations\\Chrome\\Agent.crx"));
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\HP_Reporting\\Webdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    browser = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder()
            .type(BrowserType.CHROME).build());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    driver.quit();
    browser = null;

    //Reporter.generateReport();
    //SDK.cleanup();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");

}
```

}

**But I need to configure the SDK and the Report. How can I achieve that in LeanFT 14.00?**

The `SDK` and the `Reporter` can be configured in two ways:

1. At initialization, as you attempted to do through the `ModifiableSDKConfiguration` and `ModifiableReportConfiguration`

or

2. In the test settings file (`resources/leanft.properties`). You can see [plenty details in the official help](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/latest/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TestSettingsFiles.htm#central_props_file).

You can manipulate *some* report settings at runtime as well, through the `Reporter` API:

- Set the report level: `Reporter.setReportLevel(ReportLevel.All);`
- Set the snapshot capture level `Reporter.setSnapshotCaptureLevel(CaptureLevel.All);`
- Even if you initialized the `SDK` and the `Reporter` through the base class, you can still add custom report events in the report (these work: `Reporter.reportEvent();`, `Reporter.startReportingContext();`, `Reporter.startTest();`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much for such a thorough answer - you have been very helpful. Your help and time spent on it is very much appreciated.

Comment: My goal is to keep the [tag:leanft] questions answer rate as close to 100% as possible. If this answers your question, consider accepting it. More about it [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).